# parsing csv by "," and " "

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have file with data format as

```
userid, friend id, books id, cd id
1, 11 12 14 12, 223 256 333 234 222, 22
2, 78 22, 22 66 11 29, 76 455
3, 123 22 11 234 198 122 881, 34 12 98 64, 22
```

where I need to use only user id and cd id, But I am unable to separate these fields.

My Java code as below.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CSV_test.txt"));

BufferedWriter ou =new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("users.csv"));
String str;
str = in.readLine();

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

  String[] ar = str.split(",");
  String[] ar1 = ar[1].split("");


  ou.write(ar[0]);
  ou.write(",");
  ou.write(ar1[1]);

  ou.newLine(); }
in.close();
ou.close();
}
```

Is there any issue with this?

Comment: Might I suggest using StringUtils to split on the ", "?

Comment: Maybe you could consider using some library for CSV manipulation, like [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net), if you need to make a lot of stuff related to CSV. This is not an answer for your question but could help in future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely you want

```
 String[] ar = str.split(",");
 String user = ar[0].trim();
 String cd = ar[3].trim();
```

Note that I'm trimming to remove leading/trailing spaces.

You could split using `", "` (note the trailing space) and that would remove the need to further `trim()`. It does make some assumptions however as to how your fields are separated (commas ? commas-and-spaces?) and perhaps it's worth investigating a [CSV library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

No need to reinvent the wheel. While CSV parsing is fairly simple, there are things that might be a little bit complicated (such as escaping the separator in field values). Existing libraries can do this for you, such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 for library suggestion from me too. I have been able to convince team mates at my work to use libraries for the same issue. every time they solved an issue, I gave an example that failed the implementation. that until they got tired :). there are many things to take care of that one might miss: separators occurring in the data, character set issues, etc. it will be far more simple and safer to use an existing and well tested API.